# Magento2 : Page_layout Container And Widget Configuration

Tags: magento2, layout, widget, page-layouts, containers

I'm new on Magento 2, I have created a custom theme and a custom page_layout in `/app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[ThemeDir]/Magento_Theme/page_layout/homepage.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
    <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>

    <container name="home.news" as="home_news" label="Home News" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="home-news" before="main.content" />

    <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
</referenceContainer>
```

( I created the layout.xml too )

My custom layout is referenced in the administration so I selected it for the page "Home page" under "Design"

Why the container I have created "home.news" in this page_layout isn't referenced in the administration **`"Content > Widget > Layout Update" ?`**

My idea is to reference container on the home page in order to be able to add widget into this container from the adminsitration ...

Any help are welcome ...

Thank,